# Why is 'q_format_voltaged' value not being used in the 'q_format_voltages' arithmetic line in this C code?

Tags: c, fixed-point

I am debugging a piece of code and I am not too familiar with fixed-point Q format and such so I'm testing out some code and seeing how the arithmetic works between it and other stuff. Long story short I reached a roadblock in the main function, inside the if-condition 'adc == 1', on 'q_format_voltaged' value, which is 15. But when that variable is used within line 'q_format_voltages', it seems to be 0 and 'q_format_voltage_offset' subtracts from it making 'q_format_voltages = -1.5' roughly. Why is 'q_format_voltaged' value 15 not being used and what can I do to fix it? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Define Q format parameters
#define FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS 16

int float_to_Q(float x) {
    return (int)(x * (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS)); // Multiply by 2^Q to shift the decimal point
}

float Q_to_float(int x) {
    return (float)x / (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS); // Divide by 2^Q to get the float value
}

int fixed_point_multiply(int x, int y) {
    long long result = (long long)x * y; // Perform multiplication in a wider type to avoid overflow
    // Adjust the result for the Q format representation
    result >>= FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS;
    return (int)result;
}

int fixed_point_divide(int x, int y) {
    long long result = (long long)x * (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS); // Multiply numerator by 2^Q
    result /= y; // Perform division
    return (int)result;
}

float original_voltage = 5; // Define voltage as a global variable

float original_LPF = 0;

float original_LPF_A = 0.002; 

float original_due_volt = 3;

float original_ADC_bits = 2;

float original_voltage_offset = 1.5;

volatile int DUTYCYCLE = 10;

int adc = 1;

int mode = 1;

int main() {
    int q_format_voltage = float_to_Q(original_voltage);
    int q_format_LPF = float_to_Q(original_LPF);
    int q_format_LPF_A = float_to_Q(original_LPF_A);
    int q_format_due_volt = float_to_Q(original_due_volt);
    int q_format_ADC_bits = float_to_Q(original_ADC_bits);
    int q_format_voltage_offset = float_to_Q(original_voltage_offset);
    int q_format_voltage_squared;
    int q_format_voltagem;
    int q_format_voltaged;
    int q_format_voltages;
    
    if (adc == 1) { 
        q_format_voltagem = fixed_point_multiply(DUTYCYCLE, q_format_due_volt); 
        q_format_voltaged = fixed_point_divide(q_format_voltagem, q_format_ADC_bits); 

        if (mode == 1) {
            q_format_voltages = q_format_voltaged - q_format_voltage_offset; 
            q_format_voltage_squared = fixed_point_multiply(q_format_voltages, q_format_voltages); // Square voltages
        }

        q_format_LPF = q_format_LPF - fixed_point_multiply(q_format_LPF_A, (q_format_LPF - q_format_voltage_squared)); // LPF calculation in Q16 format
    }

    // Printing results
    printf("Original voltage: %f\n", original_voltage);
    printf("Q format voltage: %d\n", q_format_voltage);
    printf("Original LPF: %f\n", original_LPF);
    printf("Q format LPF: %d\n", q_format_LPF);
    printf("Original LPF_A: %f\n", original_LPF_A);
    printf("Q format LPF_A: %d\n", q_format_LPF_A);
    printf("Original Due volt: %f\n", original_due_volt);
    printf("Q format Due volt: %d\n", q_format_due_volt);
    printf("Original ADC bits: %f\n", original_ADC_bits);
    printf("Q format ADC bits: %d\n", q_format_ADC_bits);
    printf("Original voltage offset: %f\n", original_voltage_offset);
    printf("Q format voltage offset: %d\n", q_format_voltage_offset);
    printf("dutycycle * due volt: %d\n", q_format_voltagem);
    printf("voltagem divided by adc bits: %d\n", q_format_voltaged);
    printf("voltage - voltage offset: %f\n", Q_to_float(q_format_voltages));
    printf("voltages number squared: %f\n", Q_to_float(q_format_voltage_squared));
    printf("LPF amount: %f\n", Q_to_float(q_format_LPF));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did you check your values? Sometimes a debugger is not able to show correct value of a variable. That might be caused by optimization. To be sure you could print your variable in both line.

Comment: Is it that you have not converted `DUTYCYCLE` to your Q format, but you have multiplied it using `fixed_point_multiply()`?

Comment: `q_format_ADC_bits = float_to_Q(original_ADC_bits);` Using a number of bits as Q value looks suspicious. Also dividing by that number is strange. Normally, bit numbers are used for shifting, not for calculating values

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't do left shift directly but use `* (1 << FIXED_POINT_FRACTIONAL_BITS)` instead?

Comment: You are supposed to monitor your question for a while after posting and respond to feedback. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)